# Javascript make instance of nested object

Tags: javascript, object, scope, nested

```js
function OB(a){
  this.a;

  function Node(b){
    this.b = b;
  }
}
var a = new OB("test");
var b = new Node("test2");
```

What I want to do is to make a new Node outside of OB. But I get an error. A work around would be to separate the Node constructor out of OB, but that could cause a naming conflict later if I want to use "Node" somewhere else.

Comment: What is the error you get, and which is the statement/context you call the `add` method from? What is `this.a` and `this.b` supposed to do? As you put it there, they are just expressions that do nothing. They don't create `a` or `b` properties.

Comment: I simplified the problem a bit. The error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor"

Comment: It's simple: don't do this. If you don't want a global `Node` (though you are calling it like that), put it on a namespace object - not inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your Node function is nested inside the OB function. You can't call that function from outside the parent function. You would need to do this:

```
function OB(a){
    this.a;
}
function Node(b){
    this.b = b;
}
var a = new OB("test");
var b = new Node("test2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not attach your Node function to the object that gets returned to var a?

```
function OB(a){
  this.a;
}

OB.prototype.Node = function (b){
  this.b = b;
}

var a = new OB("test");
var b = new a.Node("test2");
```

Comment: Because that creates a whole new constructor function and prototype on every call of `OB`. You don't want that for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Well, if that were the case, then he could add it to the prototype of function OB.  I think this is what the OP is aiming for.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your answer to show that better approach.